# Why ScriptManager causes postback on RequiredFieldValidator in ASP.NET (Web Forms)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager, requiredfieldvalidator

Before adding the `ScriptManager` when I was clicking on the login button it was showing the required field warning without page `postback` but after that it has started to do `postback` first and then validate fields.

It's required to add a `ScriptManager` when there is an `UpdatePanel` on the page.

How can I fix this so it doesn't `postback` on `RequiredFieldValidator`?

### Login Page

```
<form id="signinform" runat="server" defaultfocus="username" defaultbutton="LogInBtn">

    <asp:scriptmanager id="FormScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>

    <div class="form-signup">

        <div class="form-group form-group-info">
            <div class="append-icon m-b-30">
                <asp:textbox id="username" runat="server" cssclass="form-control c-white form-control-success" placeholder="Username" />
                <i class="mdi-action-perm-identity c-light"></i>
                <asp:requiredfieldvalidator runat="server" id="UserNameValidator" controltovalidate="username" display="Dynamic" validationgroup="LoginVAL" setfocusonerror="true" cssclass=" f-11 c-red m-b-0" errormessage="The username is required." />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-group-info">
            <div class="append-icon m-b-30">
                <asp:textbox id="Password" textmode="Password" runat="server" cssclass="form-control c-white form-control-success" placeholder="Password" />
                <i class=" mdi-action-lock-outline c-light"></i>
                <asp:requiredfieldvalidator runat="server" id="PasswordValidator" controltovalidate="Password" display="Dynamic" setfocusonerror="true" validationgroup="LoginVAL" cssclass="f-11 c-red m-b-0" errormessage="The password is required." />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="togglebutton togglebutton-info">
            <label class="c-light normal f-11 m-b-15">
                <input type="checkbox" runat="server" name="RememberMe" id="RememberMe" class="md-checkbox">
                Remember me?
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <asp:placeholder runat="server" id="ErrorMessage" visible="false" viewstatemode="Disabled">
        <p id="ErrorMessageContainer" runat="server" class="badge badge-danger m-b-5 f-11">
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" ViewStateMode="Disabled" />
        </p>
    </asp:placeholder>

    <div class="progress-demo">
        <asp:linkbutton id="LogInBtn" runat="server" onclick="LogIn" text="Login" cssclass="btn btn-material-indigo btn-block btn-embossed ladda-button" validationgroup="LoginVAL" data-style="zoom-in"></asp:linkbutton>
    </div>

    <p>
        <%--   Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality--%>
        <asp:hyperlink runat="server" id="ForgotPasswordHyperLink" viewstatemode="Disabled">Forgot your password?</asp:hyperlink>
    </p>


    <div class="modal fade" id="LoginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id="LoginModalHeader" runat="server" class="modal-header bg-aero">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icons-office-52"></i></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title c-white">
                        <asp:label id="LoginModalTitle" runat="server" />
                    </h4>
                </div>

                <asp:updatepanel id="LoginModalUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                        <div class="modal-body m-t-10">
                            <p class=" c-gray w-300 f-13"><asp:Label ID="LoginModalDetails" runat="server" /></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ResendConfirm" OnClick="SendEmailConfirmationToken" Text="Resend Confirmation" Visible="false" CssClass="btn btn-material-blue-grey btn-embossed" />
                            <button id="LoginModalCancel" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-embossed" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>

                    </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:updatepanel>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I appreciate your efforts in reaching a solution for my problem.

Comment: Here You can find some interesting http://forums.asp.net/t/1919818.aspx?TextBox+CausesValidation

Comment: Have you tried to place ScriptManager in body tag instead of form tag?

Comment: Yes, this came up: Control 'FormScriptManager' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: Paste your all codes like required field and texbox,etc inside the contentTemplate....

Comment: though not a direct answer to your question, to avoid the problem you are facing you can use Page.IsValid inside page_load event handler i think.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue a while back and was able to resolve it via `Page.Validate();`.

Basically, before I added ScriptManager everything was working well. When I would click the update button, the field validators would run and prevent a post back until requirements were met. After adding ScriptManager tag, the page would post back rendering my validators pretty much useless.

What I did was add on my update (submit) button click event:

```
page.validate();
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    // Your update or submit code here.
}
```

This seems to work fine!

Answer (score -1):

Write like this..

```
 <asp:updatepanel id="LoginModalUpdatePanel" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
//paste all codes inside here 
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

Comment: Please explain the reason you are suggesting this answer.it will help others

Comment: I don't need to put all of my controls inside UpdatePanel. That will open up more problems.

Comment: When you use any server side control that do PostBack whole page get refresh.that's why we use asp.net ajax library so You can enable partial rendering using ajax UpdatePanel control.update panel contain ContentTemplate that's will carry all control inside the update panel.in your code all required field codes are placed outside the update panel so it's will take whole page  PostBack.

Comment: @rajeeshmenoth I agree with you but I can't place everything under UpdatePanel since I'm using Bootstrap and some other css Styles on textbox and checkbox where they require actual postback. When I use UpdatePanel on some of those controls they actually disappear on submit method.

Comment: @Kevin Maxwell you can add your text box values separately without destroy checkbox and other function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85424/discussion-between-kevin-maxwell-and-rajeeshmenoth).

Comment: Is there any way to bypass ScriptManager?