# ScriptManager causing postbacks with validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, scriptmanager

Here is my entire page body html:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1" ID="txtTest" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txtTest" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1" Text="test" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

There is nothing in the header.  No additional .js or anything like that.

If I remove the ScriptManager, the RequiredFieldValidtor works perfectly by not allowing a postback if the textbox is not filled in (displays "Required" as expected).

With the ScriptManager in place, postback ALWAYS happens.  The error displays but postback still occurs.  What gives?  This didn't used to work this way.  Am I missing a parameter or something int he ScriptManager to allow this all to function?

**.NET VERSION COULD BE THE ISSUE**

I have determined that **this works perfectly fine in .net 4.0 and eariler** but fails if you use 4.5 and later.   Something broke in 4.5 or am I just not implementing it correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why ScriptManager causes postback on RequiredFieldValidator in ASP.NET (Web Forms)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877559/why-scriptmanager-causes-postback-on-requiredfieldvalidator-in-asp-net-web-form)

Comment: Please just edit your previous question to include additional infos after posting, don't delete then re-asking same question again (will be marked as dupe of deleted one).

Comment: the previous question was entirely different.  This was much simpler so I figured it would be better than erasing the text of the entire last post and starting over.

Comment: @Gusman that post is similar but leads no where.  They are talking about partial postback and update panels.  I posted this to make the question as simple as possible.  I wonder if it is a version of .net issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since .net version 4.5's introduction of **unobtrusive validation** it has become necessary to register your jquery resources in you **Global.asax** page as follows:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string JQueryVer = "1.7.1";
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
    {
        Path = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".min.js",
        DebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
        CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".min.js",
        CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
        CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
        LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"
    });

}
```

However you must also define the script manager properly in your markup like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="True" EnableCdn="True">
     <Scripts>
         <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
         <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" />
     </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Without enabling the Cdn the validators do not function properly and allow a postback.

This information was garnered from a variety of resources and experimenting.  In my original question, all that was necessary was defining the script manager as described above and it works fine.

Hopefully this information will allow developers to connect the dots between **postbacks** using **validators** and **unobtrusive validation**.